# Passing variable in conditions of method find() in Phalcon Framework

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phalcon, phalcon-orm

I'm receiving a variable in my controller and I want make a bind query with the search variable, I try this:

```
$search = $this->request->getPost('term');

                    $item = Item::find(
                            [
                                    'columns' => 'name',
                                    'conditions' => "name LIKE :searchT: ",
                                    'bind' => [
                                            'searchT' => '%'.$search.'%',  
                                    ],
                            ]
                            );
```

This code above is returning items that does not match with the LIKE restriction.

If I pass the string literally works fine:

```
$item = Item::find(
                            [
                                    'conditions' => "name LIKE '%Os%' ",
                                    'columns' => 'name',
                                    'limit' => 10,
                            ]
                            );
```

JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( function() {
    $("#itemSearch").autocomplete({
        source: function ( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/item/search",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { 
                    term: request.term    
                },
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function(data) {
                    response(data);
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2
    })
})
</script>
```

Comment: `LIKE :searchT:"` remove the space and check if your `$search` variable is holding some value ?

Comment: Hi, I test now and is it, now I do now why  $this->request->getPost is not receiving the data, I send the post from a JQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My $search was empty and in my JQuery I needed add a header in ajax:

```
...
source: function ( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                },  
...
```

Thanks @Abhik Chakraborty